# maven-archetype-webapp eclipse problem

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a very simple webapp with maven and eclipse, but I'm having no joy at all, in fact the reverse of joy.

I go to File -> New Project, select Maven Project, and select the maven-archetype-webapp. When I finish the wizard, a webapp structure gets generated but with no 'java' directory under main, just resources and webapp.

So I right click on main and select new Class. The class gets created under resources (?!), and furthermore, there seems to be no compilation of it by java. I can make stupid errors and no syntax highlighting comes up. It's like java isn't recognizing it.

Alternatively I have tried creating a new 'java' directory under main where it should be, but still with the same non-existent java symptoms.

What gives? This is driving me insane..

Thanks all!

Comment: Guys - thank you so much! I just tried Pascal's simple solution and it works. I'll try out all the things you all suggest.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Simply create a `java` directory under `main` (i.e. `src/main/java`) and **right-click**  on your project and select **Maven > Update Project Configuration**.

Comment: I know this is an old question but it still is a top hit on Google so just wondering if anyone is able to answer tonga's question below and explain why Maven does not simply include this as default? For example, is there a school of thought within Maven that this directory structure is not 'good' for web apps for some reason?

Answer (score 22):

1. By default, When you create a project with maven archetype "maven-archetype-webapp", it doesn't create any java and test folders.
2. You can manually add those folders as src/main/java and src/test/java.
3. After adding these folders, right click on your project in project explorer, go to maven>update project conf.

Comment: This is the strangest part of Maven. Why not create src/main/java, src/test/java, src/test/resources all together when creating webapp archetype? Isn't this a bug of Maven?

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a java directory under main (i.e. src/main/java) and right-click -> Build Path -> Use a Source Folder

Answer (score 4):

- Read the m2eclipse [WTP mini-howto](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/WTP+mini+howto).
- Check the online [Developing with Eclipse and Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/).
- Ensure your [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) is configured in the Eclipse preferences.
- Check the [m2eclipse FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Anything else is likely to be down to the archetype and how you've configured your `pom.xml`. The directory structure you describe is identical to the one `maven-archetype-webapp` creates on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create new folder named java under src/main/

Then right click on project and select maven->update project

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to create a source directory in eclipse. Or you can go to build path under project properties, and add an existing directory as a source directory.

If you are going to use non-standard directory structure you will have to specify it in maven though

Answer (score 2):

> a webapp structure gets generated but with no 'java' directory under main

Create src/main/java on your own.

> furthermore, there seems to be no compilation of it by java. I can make stupid errors and no syntax highlighting comes up. It's like java isn't recognizing it.

after creating appropriate dir structure execute the maven command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

then refresh the project in eclipse.

-SE

Comment: The OP is using m2eclipse, not the maven-eclipse-plugin

Comment: Awesome! maven-eclipse-plugin is much better than m2e.

Answer (score 2):

for src/main/java 
  your project >> properties >> java build path >> source >>
    search "Your Project src/main/java (missin)"   >>>

> > edit > folder name >> next  >> Inclusion patterns: -----> Add  >>  src/main/java
> >     OK

and if  errors still don't disapear

```
>>>  look in Target Runtimes  and check your apache in checkbox
```

Comment: Earlier i was getting compiler error asking to rename my package name to main.java.x.y.z; Following this step, Eclipse never ask for that again. Till src/main/java is on the src path. x.y.z is my package name. And now  i can write package x.y.z with out any error .Thanks

Comment: <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
     
    <!--      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Maven Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Order & Export tab, you can see the message like select 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkbox
Click OK
Now you can them

Comment: I think this answer is the cleanest way to add src/main/java and src/test/java automatically in eclipse. For current Eclipse version 2021-12 the name is "Maven Project -> Build Path -> Java Build Path"

Answer (score 1):

in IntelliJ IDEA 13 you must first create "java" folder in main folder then --> go to "open module setting"- for this you can click on project name and press f4- , and set label of "java" folder to "source" .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It works without any issue.

There could be questions regarding why all this steps are required and i believe they are pretty genuine. But this is one of the ways to make your web application or any other component working on eclipse using Maven from **command line**.

1) Open a command window

2) mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=**your package** -DartifactId=**your Project** -DarchetypeArtifactId= **your archetype. In my case "maven-archetype-webapp"** -DinteractiveMode=false

3) cd **your Project**

4) mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

5) Go to file system. Go to your newly created project. create folders, 
              a) java under main
              b) test under src
              c) java and resources under test

6) mvn eclipse:clean

7) mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

8) import **your Project** project in eclipse

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around. First make a webapp project, then add the Maven framework (in Intellij - right click project and select Add framework support). It will create the right folders for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even when i added JRE system library to my current java version but still had same problem then i just deleted JRE system library and added once again it worked for me

> - To delete JRE System Library right click on project ->properties    ->java build path -> select JRE system library -> remove
> - To add JRE go to properties->java build path -> add library ->JRE    system library -> choose JRE -> finish

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new folder "java" under src/main. will solve the problem. Because the classpath with java folder is already available in .classpath file of created project, so adding java folder will not cause any error. see below entry in .classpath file, which allows to add java folder.

```
<attributes>
<attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
<attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following steps work in eclipse 2020-06

1. File->New->Maven Project
2. Choose "Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)"
3. Choose packaging as "war" (this will create both webapp and java folders)
4. Create the project after specifying group id and artifact id
5. Update pom.xml with java and compiler versions, then right click on project, select Maven->Update project
6. If the project is not faceted form (Its not in faceted form if on expanding project in Project explorer, it doesn't show details such as "Deployment Descriptor" and "JAX-WS Web Services", this happened in one of my eclipse installation and i had no clue why), then do the following steps

   1. right click on project, go to Properties, click on Project Facets, convert to faceted form, choose correct "Dynamic Web Module" version, enable the checkbox and also choose correct Java Facet version.
   2. "Further configuration available" gets displayed in that window, click on it and specify WebContent folder. (replace WebContent by src/main/webapp)
   3. If you want to run the application in servers configured in eclipse, then specify maven dependencies to be deployed in "Deployment Assembly". This will deploy maven "provided" dependencies also, but i think its fine for testing. For actual distribution, you can supply war file generated from maven package.

Answer (score 0):

error occurs when the JRE System Library is wrongly pointed. Now go to Libraries tab and change the JRE System Library to the correct version.