# Where is my java directory?

Tags: maven, maven-2

In Maven2 I've created the maven-archetype-webapp. I see the *webapp* and *resource* directory, but where is my ***java*** directory?

Do I create it manually, and if so, would I  need to configure the *pom.xml* to recognize that this new ***java*** directory is where my classes are located?

Answer (score 7):

The webapp archetype for maven doesn't automatically create a java directory. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem/3044965#3044965), you can create it yourself.

> Simply create a java directory under
>   main (i.e. src/main/java) and
>   right-click on your project and select
>   Maven > Update Project Configuration.

Comment: This is the correct answer but that last block of instructions is for a specific IDE. The bottom line is you won't have to change your pom.xml file; Maven will automatically look in src/main/jave for your classes. YOu will only need to change your pom.xml file if you put it somewhere else, which I don't recommend.

Comment: @Gweebz: True, the "and right-click..." part is probably for Eclipse. The beginning part, about creating the directory, is the important part. Once you create it, it will automatically be picked up by maven.

Comment: Ok good to know that I wont have to configure any pom setting. Just thought that if I did need any configuration, there be a maven command for this. But sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your java directory in [src/main/java](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). This is the default source code directory and no special configuration is needed.

Comment: I assumed too it would be automatically generated and at the location you've mentioned but it isn't. heres my command. 

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mywebapp -DartifactId=myweb -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour and found that the sample webapp project of this archetype does not contain a [source](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-webapp/) directory. Just create it and you can add java code to the project.