# Eclipse Indigo and Maven : Unable to find src/main/java in dynamic web project

Tags: servlets, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I've been using Eclipse indigo with m2e and m2e-wtp installed.

I [created a dynamic web project using m2e](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/spring/project) by selecting maven-archetype-webapp. Now the problem is, I could not see src/main/java, src/test/java and src/test/resources in the created structure. Here is a snap of the project.

[image]

I stumble around and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407422/517483). I created required directories on file system. Now the question is ideally where should I add "Source Folder" for each directories(src/main/java, src/test/java and src/test/resources)? Should I add them under "Java Resources" or somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how we do it.
src/main/java, src/test/java and src/test/resources 
under java resources -> new source folder

Don't forget to add your src/main/java path and the maven dependencies to the deployment assembly of your project if you want to run the web app from eclipse via tomcat.

**EDIT**

Concerning Eclipse Deployment:

If the project is already facetted as a Dynamic Web Project like yours, you'll need to add a Server in the Server view (We use Tomcat 7 and reference a local tomcat copy in the server setup)

Then you add the web projeect to the server (add/remove on the server)

In the project properties you'll need to add the src/main/resources and src/main/java folders to your deployment assembly as well as the maven dependencies.

We also use a src/main/webapp folder instead of the webcontent folder that is automatically created. This holds the web resources, WEB-INF and views and will be added to the deployment assembly as well and mapped to the root path '/'

Now you'll run an install on your app and then select 'run on server'

Comment: You mean to say is "Source Folder" for src/main/java, src/test/java and src/test/resources will go under  "Java Resources", isn't it? I am going to deploy the application on separate tomcat instance. But I would appreciate if you elaborate more if someone wants to run the application within configured server in Eclipse itself.

Comment: Yes, that's how I meant it. I'll add in some details converning deployment in eclipse..

Comment: Thanks @Pete for Eclipse Deployment steps. Surprisingly I followed first two steps, started tomcat and still the application works like a charm. Further, WebContent folder is not getting created for me. So would you please give some details why should one have to configure deployment assembly?

Comment: might be it works for you like that. Don't recall why we changed the structure but the deployment assembly is the place I look at first if my app doesn't get deployed

Answer (score 1):

- Just after the creation of a web application based on the archetype 'maven-archetype-webapp', it is perfectly possible to run the wep application in making usage of 'run as' on Tomcat (by example). You have right to a jsp page, index.jsp.
- But if you want like many others create a servlet then you have a problem. The build path of the projects references 'src/main/java' and 'src/test/java' but the directories do net exist yet. I don't know why they forgot to create the directories (within the archetype)...
- To correct the problem, you 'simply' have to create the missing directories (from the explorer) and then from Eclipse do a right-click on the project name and then click on 'Maven' and then 'Update Project'. If you create the directories this way you will see that the source directories (src/main/java and src/test/java **will appear again**).
- Then create a new servlet (by example) in src/main/java and deploy the application again.  Everyting will work this time.