# Eclipse build not working

Tags: eclipse, git, workspace

I have set up eclipse project with maven layout. I have also enabled the maven dependency management(with m2eclipse). I can run the tests from the eclipse menu.

Now, I have initialized a git repository (external to eclipse. no plugins) inside my project and I have commited the .gitignore and pom.xml files

.gitignore

```
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
target/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath
```

Now I have created a new branch and checked it out to work. Now my autobuild is stopped working. The eclipse menu still shows "Build automatically" as ticked.

I am not what is going wrong here.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Any error message? Any private file missing after checkout your new branch? (which would be needed by maven?)

Comment: I was trying something here and there and I found that git is not the culprit. It seems when I "Enable dependency" in my m2eclipse, the auto build stops working.

Comment: It seems that my project configurations were updated somehow. I right clicked Project -> Maven->Update Project Conf. and everything is back to normal now.

Comment: Good catch. I have added it as answer with some reference for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

The [OP Varun Naik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650965/varun-naik) reports in the comment that:

> It seems when I "Enable dependency" in my m2eclipse, the auto build stops working

That seems a sign of a project configuration being no longer in sync with the Maven project:

> It seems that my project configurations were updated somehow.
>   I right clicked `Project -> Maven->Update Project Conf`,  and everything is back to normal now.

This is similar to the question "[maven-archetype-webapp eclipse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044965/6309)".