# Maven-archetype-webapp Directory Structure?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

Is there a possibility or a workaroud to use maven-archetype-webapp archetype to generate a maven webapp with plain directory structure like

```
 /src

    /main

        /java 
        /resources 
        /webapp 

    /test 
        /java 
        /resources
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven-archetype-webapp eclipse problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that your issue is the missing `java` and `test` folders in a new project when using maven-archetype-webapp. There are no options to make that archetype to add those. Of course you could add them manually after the project was created.

You may find another archetypes in one of these lists:

- http://myjeeva.com/exclusive-maven-archetype-list.html
- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List

If there is nothing that matches what you need I suggest creating an own archetype: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

It is quite easy and if you plan to use one several times it's probably worth the effort.

Comment: Any reason why they have not added it by default?

Comment: I assume because that archetype is meant to be a very simple example to start with and it's trying to not confuse developers new to maven. There are some more sophisticated archetypes available at http://appfuse.org/

Answer (score 2):

Actually I am not very sure of what you are asking, I mean are you looking for an alternative solution to maven-archetype-webapp ?

With maven archetype you can create the above mentioned directory structure without any hassle, of course java and test folders will be missing there.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.techidiocy -DartifactId=FirstWeb
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

2) If you are using eclipse IDE , then you can issue the command mentioned below to convert your maven project into an Eclipse Web Project.

```
  mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

This Step 2 is optional , if you are not planning to bind it with eclipse

Thanks