# webapp archetype doesn't create java folder

Tags: algorithm

I initialize the project with the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=tuomas -DartifactId=test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

which should create standard java webapp project structure, including `src/main/java` folder. Instead, it only creates `src/main/webapp` and `src/main/resources`, but not `src/main/java`. When I add new java class in eclipse wizard, it ends up under `src/main/resources`.

What is wrong with the maven command, and how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven-archetype-webapp Directory Structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965477/maven-archetype-webapp-directory-structure)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven-archetype-webapp eclipse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem)