# JSF page returns 403 Forbidden error despite welcome-file-list declared in web.xml

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly, http-status-code-403

I am trying to deploy a simple web page at wildfly server. But every time I try to access the page, it gives me the infamous 403 "Forbidden" error. I've tried everything I could. I've changed the file permissions of the xhtml page, I've declared it on the welcome file list in the web.xml file, but the error keeps showing up. What is wrong with it? I am using maven to build and deploy the application and Intellij ad the IDE

Structure of the file:

[image]

Note: I still did not add any Bean yet.

Comment: So if you put a plain non-jsf html file in the same location and use that in the web.xml as a welcome file it does work?

Comment: @Kukeltje Nope, still not working

Comment: Then it is not jsf related! And java-ee is waay to broad I think and please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965477/maven-archetype-webapp-directory-structure... it is 'wrong' in your project for maven (unless you have an uncommon structure, explicitily for intellij. And try with plain tomcat... Does it fail too? Then it is not wildfly related either. Check your server log for errors

Comment: What URL are you requesting?