# Maven + Spring in Eclipse: Unable to find the downloaded Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to using Maven and Eclipse, I am following [this](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-maven-web-application-in-eclipse.html) link.

Below is the **pom.xml** I have in my workspace:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.HelloWorld</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringHelloWorld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringHelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>  
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>  
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>  
    </properties> 

  <dependencies>  
   <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
       <version>${spring.version}</version>  
   </dependency>  

   <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
       <version>${spring.version}</version>  
   </dependency>  

   <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
       <version>${spring.version}</version>  
   </dependency>  

       <dependency>  
           <groupId>junit</groupId>  
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
       <version>3.8.1</version>  
       <scope>test</scope>  
       </dependency>  
   </dependencies>  

  <build>
    <finalName>SpringHelloWorld</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

For adding the required jars, I run the below command from command prompt:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

I got the "BUILD SUCCESS" message in my console. But when I refresh the project in Eclipse IDE, I can see all the libraries are missing and the path for those jars does not exists.

e.g.

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'SpringHelloWorld' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar'    SpringHelloWorld        Build path  Build Path Problem`

For this error, when I check manually, I can't see any folder named `springframework` inside the `org` folder, hence the jar is missing and the error is displaye din Eclipse IDE.

I tried running the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` multiple times but of no use.

Please advice how to resolve this.

**EDIT**

Below is the snapshot of the Eclipse Installations:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I am not getting the `Maven` option when I `Right Click` on my project in Eclipse IDE. Hence when I create the `java` folder under the `main` folder`, I am not able to`Update Project Configuration` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem). Please advice

Comment: did u install maven integration tool (m2eclipse) for eclipse?

Comment: @MironBalcerzak I have added the snapshot in above post, please check and advice if something is missing.

Comment: Are you really working on Eclispe 3.7.x?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. the file .eclipseproduct gives me this: `name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=3.7.0`

Comment: But I dont get the `Maven` option when I right Click on my project :( Please advise

Comment: Did you try "convert to maven project" in one of the options once you click on project icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try installing m2eclipse plugin (if you haven't done so yet) and nextly convert project to use maven behaviour through right clicking on project and choosing "convert to maven" option.

Answer (score 3):

The Maven command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` generate the eclipse project files from POM.

The "-D" prefix in the argument means that it's a system property.
System property are defined like `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html#SYS`

`mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` command convert the web based java project to maven based java project to support Eclipse IDE.

You can simple use given below command to clean and build your project:
    `mvn clean` and `mvn install`
OR **`mvn clean install`**

Suggestion: Check maven is installed properly using command `mvn --version`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -e clean install
```

run this instead. This builds your project by resolving dependencies

Comment: Tried but of no use; same issue exists