# How to import java file into jsp in maven webapp

Tags: maven, jsp

I use maven archetype build a webapp.
I built a java helper class for every jsp page for CRUD.
But I can not import the helper class in jsp page, got "cannot be resolved" error !

[Here is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyujE.png)
you may need click the link to see the picture.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem

Comment: Move the classes (may be whole package com.fs.cassandra) from src/main/resources to src/main/java