# Why Eclipse does not create me "scr/main/java" and "src/main/webapp" folders at the creation of a new Maven Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, maven-archetype

When I create a new Maven Project on Eclipse with the webapp achetype, Eclispe does not create me those two folders :

```
"scr/main/java"
```

and

```
"src/main/webapp"
```

I tried to reinstall a new version of Eclipse but the result is the same.

Does someone know what is goin'on ?

Thank you [image]

Comment: Eclipse doesn't show empty folders by default. There's an option to show them. Click the three vertical dots to the right of "Project Explorer" in your screencap, then "Filters and Customization". On the "Pre-set filters" tab, I think you're looking for just "empty packages". But there are several "empty" options. Note matches will not be displayed.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't fix the problem. I should probably start to use net beans ^^

Comment: You haven't fully expanded the "src" folder, so we don't actually see if there's really a problem.

Comment: What was the full archetype name you selected?

Comment: I choose the main webapp archetype...

Comment: i'm facing the same problem. I think it is duplicate question = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042518/maven-archetype-webapp-eclipse-problem